# Single big BST vs multiple smaller BSTs? Which is faster for search?

Tags: time-complexity

Lets say that I am storing `10^9` keys in a single BST. 
Compared to having lets say having multiple BSTs of sizes `10^6` containing chunk of the bigger tree? Search through all of them executing in parallel.

I am talking about only search performance here, Given that processing power is not a bottle neck.

Comment: Do the $1000$ BSTs cover disjoint ranges, or do you allow the range of keys to overlap? I would think that they do not overlap, in which case a parallel search doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 2):

Searching among $N$ in a BST takes (roughly) $\log_2 N$ comparisons. So searching in $10^9 \approx 2^{30}$ takes around 30 comparisons. Searching in $10^6 \approx 2^{20}$ takes 20 comparisons. The cost of farming out the work to 1000 processors, collecting the results and figuring out the answer is surely costlier than 10 comparisons.